Nuxt-i18n : Retrieve and loop arrays from translation messages or json files
Please help. I am trying i18n with Nuxt 3 using @nuxtjs/i18n package and hit a road block retrieving arrays form translation documents as is. The value comes as abstract syntax tree using $tm, as below:
Whats expected is
[
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "price": "Price 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
        "price": "Price 2"
      }
    ]

but what i receive is
[
  {
    "title": {
      "type": 0,
      "start": 0,
      "end": 7,
      "loc": {
        "start": {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 1,
          "offset": 0
        },
        "end": {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 8,
          "offset": 7
        },
        "source": "Title 1"
      },
...
...
..

here is the sample code of the test page, with the issue
<i18n lang="json">
{
  "en": {
    "summary": [
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "price": "Price 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
        "price": "Price 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</i18n>
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <pre>{{ $tm('summary') }}</pre>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { t, tm, rt } = useI18n()


</script>

Codesandbox reproduction
Can someone help how to properly retrive arrays and objects as is from translation messages? It used to work as expected in previous version of i18n with Nuxt 2 and $t
Thank you

This is what compiled messages look like. It's ok. They may not exist in original form in the app as this would require to store excessive data. What do you want to achieve? This could be XY problem

It is not possible anymore to obtain the original JSON using the i18n lib.
This issue and this piece of the documentation are about your question as well.

The translation API like $t and t function that return string only.
Object and array values are no longer returned.

If this behaviour is what you want, you should store it in a cache and retrieve it when you want.
If you want to retrieve the translated locales using i18n you can achieve that in two ways:
  <template>
    <div>
      <NuxtLink :to="switchLocalePath('de')"> DE </NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink :to="switchLocalePath('en')"> EN </NuxtLink>


      <div v-for="(item, index) in summary" :key="index">
        <h1> 1st approach: {{ t(`summary[${index}].title`) }}  </h1>
        <h1> 2nd approach: {{ item.title.body.static }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  
  const { t, tm } = useI18n()
  const summary = tm('summary') 
  
  </script>


The right way to do this is using the rt component
const { t, tm, rt } useI18n()

Your code seems to use local  blocks in SFC, so the useScope must be set to "local"
const { t, tm, rt } useI18n({
useScope: "local"
})

The right way to loop in this new version (vue3 & Nuxt3) is using tm and rt.
<script setup>
const { t, tm, rt } = useI18n()
</script>

<template>
  <div>

    <div v-for="sum in tm('summary')" :key="sum.price">
      <pre>{{ rt(sum.title) }}</pre>
      <pre>{{ rt(sum.description) }}</pre>
      <pre>{{ rt(sum.price) }}</pre>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<i18n lang="json">
{
  "en": {
    "summary": [
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "price": "Price 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
        "price": "Price 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</i18n>


